# Monit system cpu usage

Tags: monitoring, ubuntu-10.04, cpu-usage, monit

Monit version: 5.0.3
Server: Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS

I want to monitor the system cpu usage with Monit and I am trying as follows:

```
check system host_name
   if cpu usage (user) > 70% then alert
   if cpu usage (system) > 30% then alert
   if cpu usage (wait) > 20% then alert
```

But when I use this command:

```
monit -v
```

The response is:

```
'host_name' cpu wait usage check succeeded [current cpu wait usage=-1.0%]
'host_name' cpu system usage check succeeded [current cpu system usage=-1.0%]
'host_name' cpu user usage check succeeded [current cpu user usage=-1.0%]
```

I guess it is not working :) Why do I get this message? The cpu usage is not -1.0% of course, so why do I get this false result?

Comment: Also, can you update to a more current Monit? Today's version is 5.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have this result because no check has already been performed.

I would suggest to edit file `/etc/monit/monitrc` and uncomment line :

```
set daemon  120
```

Then restart monit : `/etc/init.d/monit restart`

Should be OK.

The fact is that your `monit` version comes with a control file fully commented.